# Can BaseColumns._ID be used as an ID in multiple tables

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have 2 tables in my database and I plan to use Cursor class to show the data in those tables to the user. Can I use BaseColumns._ID as an ID column in those tables and then fetch the data with Cursor?

Comment: That depends. Two lists, or a join?

Comment: two separate lists